# How to implement generic resource using REST with Dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

How to implement  generic resource using REST with Dropwizard to fetch the list of entity.So that we can use this generic resourse just by giving the entity name.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple example. What you need to do is just to create concrete classes out of this and add them to your jersey as resources. You don't need to override methods unless you want to.

```
public abstract class GenericResource<T extends GenericObject> {

  protected HashMap<UUID, T> database = new HashMap<>();

  @GET
  public Collection<T> list() {
    return database.values();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  public T get(@PathParam("id") UUID id) {
    return database.get(id);
  }

  @POST
  public T save(T t) throws Exception {
    if (database.containsKey(t.getId())) {
      throw new Exception("an item already exists with given id " + t.getId());
    }

    database.put(t.getId(), t);

    return t;
  }

  @PUT
  public T update(T t) throws Exception {
    if (!database.containsKey(t.getId())) {
      throw new Exception("an item does not exist with given id " + t.getId());
    }

    database.put(t.getId(), t);

    return t;
  }


  @DELETE
  @Path("/{id}")
  public void delete(@PathParam("id") UUID id) throws Exception {
    if (database.containsKey(id)) {
      throw new Exception("an item already exists with given id " + id);
    }

    database.remove(id);
  }
}
```